# Write a complete list into a text file in Python

Tags: python, list, file, text

I got a list like this that I got reading a temporary text file before.

```
['Usain','Jamaican','9','2','0']
```

But now I need to write this list into a new text file that contains a list with lists. The text file should look like this:

```
  [['Usain','Jamaican','9','2','0'], ['Christopher', 'Costarican', '0','1',2']]
```

I've tried to write the list into a text file, but I just import the elements on the list and write them as newlines.

my code looks like this

```
  def terminar():
    with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
      registroFinal = [line.strip() for line in f]
    final = open('final.txt','a')
    for item in registroFinal:
      final.write("%s\n" % item)
    os.remove('temp.txt')
```

Comment: `final.write("%s\n" % repr(item))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use json to dump out the list of lists:

```
import json
with open('final.txt','a') as final:
    json.dump(registroFinal, final)
```

You would load this in with `json.load()`. Otherwise you could use `repr(registroFinal)` to write out the representation into a file. How is this data going to be used? If you plan to read it back into a python object I would favour the json approach.

Python also has the facility to manage temporary files, see `tempfile` module